# SQL Server CE - bad performance

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce

I'm developing an application that uses a SQL Server CE database and I am having trouble with the performance of the queries. For example, a simple query that gets the customer's last order:

```
SELECT 
    Customer.Name, Orders.Amount AS LastOrderAmount
FROM   
    Customers
LEFT JOIN 
    Orders ON Orders.OrderId IN (SELECT TOP(1) OrderId
                                 FROM Orders 
                                 WHERE CustomerId = Customer.CustomerId 
                                 ORDER BY OrderNum DESC)
```

This query is incredibly slow. With only 30 costumers and about 300 orders it takes almost 10 seconds to finish!

I'm querying using `SqlCEDataAdapter`. I also tried using `SqlCeResultSet`, but the difference is negligible. Also, I have an index on `Orders.CustomerId` (creating it didn't make much difference, though).

Now, I'm not expecting miracles from SQL Server CE, but this is just terrible. So, is there something I can do to improve performance or is it just THAT slow?

Comment: do you have any indexes?

Comment: Customer.CustomerId and Order.OrderId are primary keys, Order.CustomerId is indexed.

Comment: Your query just seems odd (what is `Ciklus.CiklusId`?). I think your results could be obtained with MAX and GROUP BY syntax. Maybe post the table structures and someone will write an efficient query for this. Agreed that 10 seconds is ludicrous for this task.

Comment: 1. Where is the `Ciklus` table? 2. You shouldn't use `TOP 1` and `ORDER BY` in that way, you should use `max(OrderNum)`

Comment: Oh, sorry, that's a typo when I was editing the query. I can't use MAX as I need the whole Order row. I've edited the query to make it more clear.

Comment: Also, as SqlCE doesn't support subqueries that return a single value, I have to use IN instead of = in the JOIN ON clause.

Comment: If you need the whole Order row, you should include that in the query because it definitely changes the problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT cus.Name
     , outerOrd.Amount AS LastOrderAmount
  FROM Customers cus
  LEFT JOIN Orders outerOrd on outerOrd.CustomerId = cus.CustomerId
 WHERE not exists (SELECT *
                     FROM Orders innerOrd
                    WHERE innerOrd.CustomerId = cus.CustomerId
                      and innerOrd.OrderId > outerOrd.OrderId 
                  )
```

Edited, probably this is better:

```
SELECT cus.Name
     , ord.Amount AS LastOrderAmount
  FROM Customers cus
  LEFT JOIN Orders ord on ord.CustomerId = cus.CustomerId
 WHERE ord.OrderId = (SELECT max(OrderId)
                        FROM Orders
                       WHERE CustomerId = cus.CustomerId
                     )
```

Comment: Whoa, that is a LOT faster. Thanks! Still, it's lame that the other query is performed so slow.

Comment: @kolufild check the second query I've just added. I think is better.

Comment: The second query doesn't work, because SqlCE doesn't support subqueries that return a single value. So, `ord.OrderId = (SELECT` throws an error.

Comment: I think the LEFT JOIN is redundant. I mean, since your intention is to get the last order amount for each customer, why do you want all the customers with no orders? A simple join then should be enough. I think you should try to Join Customers with a subquery that gets the last order for each customer. No need to Join Customers with Orders with <whatever subquery>.